# Error: Font t1-zi4r-4 at 480 not found (TeXLive)

Tags: fonts, errors, acmart, inconsolata

I am trying to use `acmart.cls` to write a journal article.  I am using the `verbatim` environment to include code snippets in the article.  I understand that the ACM class uses the Inconsolata font as the fixed-width font.  When I try to compile my article, no PDF is produced and the `.log` file includes the following error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file t1-zi4r-4): Font t1-zi4r-4 at 480 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have seen references to this error occurring with MikTeX, but I am running TeXLive 2020 on a High Sierra macBook.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I might resolve this error?

(One option might be to install TeXLive 2021, but that appears to require Mojave or later, and that is not something I want to upgrade to right now -- I have some concerns that some of my assistive technology software may not work on Mojave or later.)

In case it is helpful, here is the complete [`.log` file](https://pastebin.com/H7bEbLd0).  And here is an example document that tries to use Inconsolata/`zi4` but fails with a very similar error (`ot1-zi4r-4 at 600 not found`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[varqu]{zi4}

\begin{document}

Here is some \verb`code`.
And here is something longer.
\begin{verbatim}
  fun map f [] = []
    | map f (x::xs) = (f x)::(map f xs)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This means the font  is not mentioned in the files `pdftex.map` & friends, and the system tries to make .pk fonts. Maybe try `initexmf --mkmaps` from the console.

Comment: @Bernard It says: `sudo: initexmf: command not found`.  Is `initexmf` part of TeXLive?

Comment: you should show a complete example so that one can test if the font is actually needed in a current system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to add what you are looking for.  Please let me know if you meant something different.  Thanks!

Comment: @HenryDeYoung: I don't know. This is used under MiKTeX, but I'm sure that in the documentation of TeX Live, there is an equivalent command to refresh the type 1 fonts database.

Comment: run `updmap-sys`. It will tell you at the begin where it writes its map file. Check if this contains `/Users/hdeyoung/Library/texlive/2020basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`. If *not* try to remove this map, perhaps it shadows the main map.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, it seems to be using `/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap`.  So, I should try to remove this `/usr/local/`... map?  (For your information, the user `hdeyoung` is not an administrator, so I had to `su admin` and `sudo updmap-sys`.)

Comment: try at first what happens if you remove (or rename) the hdeyoung map.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much!!  That worked perfectly!  Is there anywhere that I could read more about how fonts are managed in (La)TeX?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you'd like to convert your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a local pdftex.map in `/Users/hdeyoung/Library` (perhaps created at some time with a `updmap` call) which shadows the system map file. Remove or rename it.
(If there are other map files, it would be probably good to remove them too)